# How to export ICO files to use as Windows folder icons

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, icon

**How can I export a file that you could set it as a folder icon in Windows 7? And also, how do you get an application that has only one icon to change it's size when re-scaling?** I set folder options to display large icons instead of normal and it changes icon, but when I go to application folder there is only one icon file.

I could actually export it targa (TGA) format then I can set it as an icon, but transparency is set to black and quality is terrible.

I browsed the Adobe forums and I couldn't find a solution anywhere. There are a lot of websites that convert PNG/JPG photos to ICO files, but I'd like to find out how to do it myself.

Using Adobe Illustrator CS6, Photoshop CS6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Illustrator and Photoshop are not really icon file constructors in some ways.

Sure you can create artwork and save it as an icon. However, .ico or icon *files* can have layers of different icons for different sizes.

For example, take a look at this screen shot from [IconBuilder](http://iconfactory.com/software/iconbuilder/) on the Mac:

[image: screenshot]

You can see that the actual icon file contains separate images for each size of the icon. This is what icon software does specifically - stack various sizes. You can not achieve this with either Illustrator or Photoshop alone. You need icon building software or plug ins.

Comment: Thank you I 5 mins before your answer I found a website http://www.converticon.com/ it can convert pictures to icons of various resolutions. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume if there's one file, it's one large file that's scaled down when necessary.

Comment: I tought so but what if they change when you rescale them?

Comment: By the way. I just examined that file and it's about 16x16...

Answer (score 0):

For all those people who don't need different sizes in a single icon, there's a photoshop plugin to save your graphic as an ICO file: http://www.telegraphics.com.au/sw/